# How to exclude only the binary files using .hgignore?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I have a directory `data-files-dir` containing files with the following extensions:

```
# binary types
.dat
.dat.gz
.csv

# script files
.bat
.yaml
```

I want to exclude the binary files which contain gigabytes worth of data that I don't want stored in Mercurial.

But I want to have the script files recorded by Mercurial.

So far the best I could do is the exclude the entire directory using this `.hgignore` file:

```
syntax: glob
data-files-dir/**
```

But I can no longer afford to exclude these script files from Mercurial.

How do I have Mercurial track the script files but not the binary files?

Comment: I was thinking that - however I assume that a CSV file would be too large to worry about including.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the example specified in [hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html), does the following not work?

```
syntax: glob
*.dat
*.dat.gz
*.csv
```

Comment: This would also ignore files outside of the `data-files-dir` directory, which may not be desired. I would suggest adding the path also.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the files using regexp syntax to be more concise.  The following example `.hgignore` file uses both `glob` and `regexp` syntax.  The glob entries ignore everything under the `bin` and `obj` directories.  The `regexp` item ignores all files under the `data-files-dir` that end with the extensions listed in the parenthesis.

```
syntax:glob
bin/**
obj/**

sytnax:regexp
data-files-dir/.+\.(dat|gz|csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files you wish to ignore are all in the `data-files-dir` directory, then you can add the following to your `.hgignore` file:

```
glob:data-files-dir/*.dat
glob:data-files-dir/*.gz
glob:data-files-dir/*.csv
```

This will ignore those file extensions only in the `data-files-dir` directory.  I just tried a quick test, and it seems to work for me:

```
C:\ignoretest>dir /b data-files-dir
batch.bat
binary1.dat
binary2.dat
binary2.gz
C:\ignoretest>hg st
? .hgignore
? data-files-dir\batch.bat
```

So any `.dat`, `.gz` or `.csv` file is ignored with the above in my `.hgignore` file.